# Geolocation for iPhone JavaScript Web App

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, geolocation

I am building a full-stack web app in JavaScript that is intended to be used on mobile devices (Android and iPhone). Using the HTML5 Geolocation API on Android phones works great, but there appears to be an authorization issue with the iPhone. When interacting with the web app as an iPhone user, iOS automatically denies the user permission to use location services, and so unlike the Android phones, there is no pop-up that gives the user the option to allow location services. I've done a lot of tinkering with the iPhone location services settings to no avail. Is there a JavaScript snippet that enables the user to allow permission for location services? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your location setting for Safari might be set to `OFF`, you can change it here: `Settings > Privacy > Location Services > Safari`

You could also try something like this:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction);
} else {
    // Make API call to the GeoIP services
}
```

And use some service like http://ip-api.com (but geodata based on ip is not very accurate)

Here you can find more info about getCurrentPosition():

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition
- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/GettingGeographicalLocations/GettingGeographicalLocations.html

Comment: http://ip-api.com is decently accurate, but you have to be connected to wi-fi to use it. I was able to use http://freegeoip.net's API, but the geodata is WAY off showing I'm in Houston (when I'm actually in Austin). This may have to be the work around for now and I'll enable user's to edit the lat / lon produced by this API. It's too bad I still can't figure out how to access location services on the iPhone through my web app! Anyways thanks for your help.